# Returning strings from array that are not included in records field's result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have table `Animal` with a field `specie`

specie can be `["dog", "cat", "lion", "bird", "elephant", ...]`

We know that we can also find all records by:

```
@animals = Animal.all.where(specie: ["dog", "cat", "lion", "bird", "elephant", ...] )
```

Suppose that I have 10.000 records and 10.000 different possible species that can be registered. I just want an array with all the species that were **not included** yet on my database. How can I do that with the most efficient way ?

Comment: Hi, thank you but when you do Animal.all.where.not(specie: ["dog", "cat", "lion", "bird", "elephant"] ) you will find no records...

Comment: I think need to make separate table "species" and make it relational with "animals"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of the known species in memory somewhere:

```rb
species = ["dog", "cat", "lion", "bird", "elephant", ...]
missing_species = species - Animal.distinct.pluck(:specie)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also agree with @chaitanya. keeping a 10k strings in RAM is not efficient at all. its better to create a species table and do a left join with Animal. then you can exclude intersecting species.

```
class Specie
  has_many :animals
  field :name
end

class Animal
  belongs_to :specie
end

Specie.left_joins(:animals).where('animals.id' => nil).distinct.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: In this scenario you're right. In my case I need an array because the number 10.000 is just to say that I don't want to create a each loop so it has a slow performance.